# webpack or babel-loader can't find module in node_modules which is required by another module in node_modules

Tags: webpack, node-modules, webpack-4, chakra-ui

maybe someone faced similar issue. I have a project which is built with webpack. ( webpack version is 4.43.0 ). It works perfectly, but recently I have added new dependency and now when I try to build my project it shows me `ERROR: "export 'dequal' was not found in 'dequal'`. The main point which confuse me most of all that it is in dependency of dependency. To be more concrete, I've added `@chakra-ui` package and it has `dequal` package as dependency.

Screenshot of error output [image]

I have checked node_modules folder and I can find dequal in it.

In place where dequal is imported in @chakra-ui it is imported as named import:[image]

dequal package itself are exported as named export:[image]

So everything should be fine, but somehow webpack and babel-loader can't find it.
Also if I change named export in dequal package to default export and to default import in charka-ui everything are built well. So is there is something that I maybe missed in webpack config or it is a bug in webpack/babel-loader itself?
Please advise, Thanks!

Webpack: 4.43.0
babel-loader: 8.1.0
@chakra-ui/core: 1.0.0-rc.8

Comment: Try to remove node_modules & re-install it, maybe it is an installation order bug

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help